# Styled select box with long options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to implement a custom select box with a max-width that's less than that of the options.

Styling the select box is easy enough (tons of guides are available [all over the internet](http://bit.ly/13bwWfc)), here's my implementation of it:

HTML:

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select>
        <option selected>All</option>
        <option>A short option</option>
        <option>A long option with way too much text</option>
        <option>Another way too long option, but even longer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
styled-select {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    background: #6d6d6d url("dropdown-image.png") 95% 50% no-repeat;
    padding: 5px;
}

.styled-select select {
    width: 130%;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bx131j42/) to illustrate my problem. The extremely long string in the CSS is just a Base 64 encoded image.

Once a long option is selected, it will overflow the "fake" dropdown button and wreck havoc to my design. How can I hide the text overflowing the button, while still having a clickable "fake" button?

Comment: Add `padding-right: 90px;` to your `.styled-select select`?

Comment: @putvande - didn't do the trick. :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bx131j42/2/ ? You meant that the text is overflowing the arrow right? And this doesn't work? What browser are you using?

Comment: Nope, makes no difference. Newest Chrome on OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My trick is to move the arrow into a pseudo-element, and position it absolutely within the `.styled-select` element. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/bx131j42/3/

```
.styled-select {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #6d6d6d;
}
.styled-select::before {
    pointer-events: none;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20%;
    background: #6d6d6d;
    background-image: (...);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

`pointer-events: none` is to ensure that the click event on the pseudo-element is ignored and passed to the `<select>` element lying underneath (which has a lower z-index). However, some browsers (IE10 and below, for example) [do not support this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). To circumvent this, you will have to use a real element (instead of a pseudo element, see my comment) and listen to the click handler on that element, and pass it off as a `.focus()` event on the `<select>` element, e.g.:

Markup:

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <span class="dummy-arrow"></span>
    <select><!-- options --></select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dummy-arrow').click(function() {
        $(this).next('select').focus();
    });
});
```

Some tips:

- `<select>` elements are notoriously hard to style because its appearance is highly OS specific. Some browsers/OS will honour the `appearance: none` declaration, but don't count on it. Instead, you might want to rely on a JS-based replacement/dummy.
- If you want to remove the blue border around the select element on focus, use `outline: none`. However, note that this might affect usability of the site (if your select menu is not visually obvious).

Comment: Looks great, and works as you'd expect. Now - the kicker: IE7 compatibility. I don't care if it looks crap there, but still needs to work

Comment: Then instead of using a pseudo element, use a blank `<span>` or `<div>` instead. The same CSS styles apply. I expect IE7 to honour the absolute positioning part (that's very basic). Note that `pointer-events` [does not work for IE10 and below](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: that's totally acceptable. Thank you so much man, answer accepted!